# Track slide views in carousel with google analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, slider, carousel

I have a slider/carousel with a number of slides. 
The slides carry information but no links. 
I want to track how many times each slide is viewed.
I'm assuming some sort of event tracking, but I cannot use onClick as the user isn't actually clicking anything unique. The clocks are just 'next' and 'prev'.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable to track the state of the carousel.

```
var slide = 1;
```

Then when the user clicks the next or previous, you increment or decrement the variable, and send the value of the variable to Google analytics using the `_trackEvent` method.

```
$("nextbutton").click(function() {
  slide ++;
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Carousel', 'Slide'+slide ]);
});

$("prevbutton").click(function() {
  slide --;
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Carousel', 'Slide'+slide ]);
});
```

This part may need to be rewritten depending on whether you can use `gaq.push()` inside your jQuery code which I haven't tested. The increment decrement method would also need to be more complicated if the carousel allows the user to go backwards from slide 1 to the last slide.

Comment: Hi Thanks - that's a great solution for the buttons - I will try it out. The only problem is that this site is being viewed on Touch devices, where they have the ability to 'swipe' the slides - so they aren't actually interacting with the buttons.

Comment: you can still use the same technique, you just need to trigger the increment and GA call on the swipe function.

Comment: I tried the code supplied, but for some reason the event isn't being tracked. It all looks right, but nothing comes up in my realtime stats... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused as to how to create the variable

    var slide = 1;


On it's own doesn't relate to anything?